# May EMV Application File Locator not include any CVM list?

Tags: emv

Upon sending the `GET PROCESSING OPTIONS` command to a VISA card via the contactless interface, I got back the following AFL in the response:

```
94 0C 10 01 02 01 18 02 02 00 18 04 04 00
```

which decodes to:

```
SFI 1, records 1-2
SFI 3, record 2
SFI 3, record 4
```

None of those records contained a CVM list. However, by just trying to read other files and records I found one in file 5, record 1. Is this a configuration error or can it be valid not to include a CVM list in the AFL (for example in Visa's qVSDC application)? If so, how should the terminal know where to look for the CVMs?

Answer (score 1):

It's how it's supposed to look for qVSDC. CTQ is used for that purpose.

Comment: Hi Michal, even CTQ is not mandatory. is it that one of them(CVL List ) should be present.

Comment: @Adarsh You are right - it's not mandatory, but when it's not present the method is selected based on the reader capabilities in specified order. CVM List is not used in qVSDC/Kernel C-3 path.

Comment: @MichalGluchowski Thank you for pointing that out! I wasn't aware of the specifics of qVSDC processing, yet.